# How do I count only as one attempt if they input the same number multiple times consecutively?

Tags: python

Tried to make a guessing game that counts the number of attempts but I don't know how to count only as one attempt if they input the same number multiple times consecutively

```
import random

repeat = 'y'
i=1
while repeat.lower() == 'y':
    
    n = int(input("Enter value of n(1 - 100) "))
    n2 =int(input("Enter value of n2(1 - 100) "))
    a= random.randrange(n, n2)
    guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))



    while guess !=a:
        print('entry number:',i)
             
        if guess<a:
            print("you need to guess higher. Try again")
            guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))
        if guess>a:
            print("you need to guess lower. Try again")
            guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))
        if guess == a:
            print('it took you:',i,'tries to guess the hidden number')
            print('Congratulations, the hidden number is',a)
    repeat = input("\nDo you want to try again Y/N?  \n>>> ")
        
while repeat.lower() == 'n': 
    print('thank you')
    break
```

Comment: You need to store the last number that got input and compare it to the latest number that got input.

Comment: @Tarik  tbh, i don't know how to do that, I am still a complete beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.
You may also want to also store the two numbers in a list and sort the list after getting them so the program does not crash if the second number is lower.
You may want to print out the number of guesses it took when a user gets the correct answer.

`````
import random

repeat = 'y'
i=0
while repeat.lower() == 'y':
    
    n = int(input("Enter value of n(1 - 100) "))
    n2 =int(input("Enter value of n2(1 - 100) "))
    a= random.randrange(n, n2)
    guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))

    guessList = []

    while guess != a:
      if guess not in guessList:
        print('here')
        guessList.append(guess)
        i += 1
        print('entry number:',i)
             
        if guess<a:
            print("you need to guess higher. Try again")
            guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))
        if guess>a:
            print("you need to guess lower. Try again")
            guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))
        if guess == a:
            print('it took you:',i,'tries to guess the hidden number')
            print('Congratulations, the hidden number is',a)
      else:
        print("Duplicate guess try again.")
        guess = int(input("Guess the hidden number"))
    repeat = input("\nDo you want to try again Y/N?  \n>>> ")
        
while repeat.lower() == 'n': 
    print('thank you')
    break````
`````

Comment: can i ask what does this do (guessList.append(guess)) ?

Comment: Of course, it adds it to the end of the list. For example, if you an empty list.      
````list1 = [] list1.append(1) print(list1) would print [1] list1.append(2) print(list1) would print [1,2]````

Comment: and how about this part? (if guess not in guessList:)
sorry for the question, I'm still really new.

Comment: No worries, that checks to make sure that the guess is not in the list. The list keeps track of all of the previous guesses . If the guess is not within the list, then it accepts it. If it already exists within the list then it will let the user know they have already guessed it.

Comment: thanks, it really helped. Guess I need to practice more using those. thanks again

Comment: Try running this code for a better understanding. Let me know if it helps.````tempList = []
while True:
  guess = input('Input your guess: ')
  if guess not in tempList:
    tempList.append(guess)
  else:
    print('The number is already in the list.')
  print('Templist = ' + str(tempList))````

Comment: I tried running it, when I entered the same number multiples times, it does not print the else part

Comment: Try this. [UnderstandAppend](https://replit.com/@Hsmitty/stackoverflow#main.py)

Comment: ohh so the .append would add to the existing list.

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: you really helped me, I will try other problems that use this.